# Windows timers - how do they work?

Tags: windows, timer, kernel

I know that until Windows 7 the standard kernel ticks were each 15.6 ms, and that this can be modified using timeBeginPeriod and timeEndPeriod. With Win 8 the kernel apparently was made tickless.

But from this information I can not infer on how timers work. I can imagine, that there is a routine checking every 15.6 ms (or whatever the current resolution is, and for Win8+, idk) within a sorted list containing all currently active timers' desired notification times, probably expressed in ms elapsed since system start. It would just need to check the first few timers (until it finds a timer which is not ready yet) to notify the correct client, und re-insert into the list at the proper position the next timing event.

This is what I probably would do conceptionally, but folks at MS surely pondered this for much longer time than me, only that I can not find information about it. (Maybe there is a little man sitting in the Kernel doing this task?)

So, if anyone knows how this gets done, I would appreciate an explanation. Links welcome.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for implementation details when contractual documentation is readily available is not a practical programming problem.

Comment: @IInspectable, could you please point me towards a documentation explaining how timers work? I was not able to find any.

Comment: [Guidelines For Providing Multimedia Timer Support](http://web.archive.org/web/20140213124142/http:/msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463347.aspx) and [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This is not formally documented but Mark Russinovich has done the reverse-engineering work.  And written it up in his Windows Internals book.  Required reading when you have a question like this.

Comment: There is no documentation, how timers are implemented. There is documentation in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/) that describes the public interface for all supported timers.

Comment: see **"Windows Internals Part 1, 6th Edition, Chapter 3 Systems Mechanisms, Timer Processing"**, published 3/15/2012. You may buy the book to help Mark. However you may also find a pdf online if you don't have the $ 40,00 for the the book.

Comment: Just purchased both volumes. Thank yous! Shall I proceed now to remove this question, as it was suggested it's off topic?

Comment: Why remove? by now it contains valuable information maybe useful for others.